# Erro ao carregar Library MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, monodevelop

Estou tentando usar a biblioteca Newtonsoft.Json no mono, mas recebo o seguinte erro:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
```

Comment: como você adicionou essa biblioteca no projeto? pelo nugget?

Comment: Fui em References e adicionei por lá.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema, abri a pasta de instalação do MonoDevelop e procurei por Newtonsoft.Json.dll, copiei para a pasta do meu projeto, fui em References e adicionei como externa. A principio ele não carregou o iconi de Library, mas compilou e executou corretamente.